# PgwModal and DataTables

Tags: jquery, datatables, pgwmodal

I am putting a DataTable inside of a PgwModal and the default functionality of DataTables doesn't work. Can't sort, search or use the pagination buttons. Also the column headers don't line up.

Any ideas/help as to how I can get this to work?

Here's how I'm trying to pair the two:

https://jsfiddle.net/Jc3web/c1ajbh2z/1/

```
[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/Jc3web/c1ajbh2z/1/
```

Comment: please provide your code so we can help you

Comment: there is nothing

Comment: Sorry code was too long added a JS Fiddle example.

Comment: why you dont use another modal?

Comment: it seem it's an issue in the plugin I think you've looked for issues in github https://github.com/Pagawa/PgwModal/issues/20

Comment: Thank you for your time in reviewing this...

Comment: I've tried manythings with code provided but it didn't work, if you must use it you will edit plugin code